# Get distinct result from ordered result of subquery in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

We are working with oracle database. I need result in sorted order. So I have created a query that sort on id first then I have applied query over subquery result to get distinct para.

Query is :

```
select distinct(para) 
from (
    select para, id 
    from book 
    where title='2' 
      and chapter_id='2' 
      and subchap='1' 
      and para is not null 
    order by id) 
order by para
```

This return list as :

```
a
aa
aaa
bb
c
d
dd
```

But I want this list as :

```
a
c
d
aa
bb
dd
aaa
```

I want list of distinct para list? How can I achieve this using oracle query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get distinct `para`s ordered by their ids. You can try the following query:

```
SELECT para
FROM book 
WHERE title='2' 
  and chapter_id='2' 
  and subchap='1' 
  and para is not null 
GROUP BY para
ORDER BY MIN(id)
```

Notice, that it sorts on `MIN(id)` so if `para` has multiple ids it will be sorted by the smallest one.

If `para, id` combination is unique, you can group by both fields:

```
SELECT para
FROM book 
WHERE title='2' 
  and chapter_id='2' 
  and subchap='1' 
  and para is not null 
GROUP BY para, id
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. MIN(id) query working fine in my case, though I have multiple ids in para but I need only distinct para one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just want to order by length first (at least this approach matches your example):

```
select distinct(para) from 
   (select para, id from book where title='2' and chapter_id='2' and subchap='1' and para is not null) 
   order by length(para), para
```

Or maybe you want to sort by id, in this case, you need something like this:

```
select para from 
   (select para, min(id) as minid from book where title='2' and chapter_id='2' and subchap='1' and para is not null group by para) 
   order by minid
```